# empty result set yajra datatable on large tables

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a `Question` Model by about **30,000** records like this:

```
class Question extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $primaryKey = 'question_id';

        protected $fillable   = ['text', 'code', 'cat', 'answer', 'confirmed', 'is_private', 'email', 'parent', 'expert'];

        public function sub_questions ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'parent', 'question_id');
        }

        public function latest_sub_question ()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(Question::class, 'parent', 'question_id')->latest();
        }


    }
```

To show a list of all questions I'm using [yajra datatable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) laravel package.

This is my js code :

```
var allQuestionsTable =
$('#allQuestionsTable').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "responsive": true,
                        ajax: {
                            url: '{!! route('admin.questionsDatatable') !!}'
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {data: 'checkbox'},
                            {data: 'code', name: 'code'},
                            {data: 'text', name: 'text'},
                            {data: 'created_at'},
                            {data: 'answer', name: 'answer'},
                            {data: 'expert'},
                            {data: 'confirmed'},
                            {data: 'actions'}
                        ]
                    });
```

And in the back-end I wrote this function:

```
public function questionsDatatable (Request $request)
        {
            $questions = Question::with('latest_sub_question')->whereNull('parent');

            $datatable = app('datatables')->of($questions)
                ->addColumn('checkbox', '<input type="checkbox" name="item_id[]" value="{{$question_id}}" id="Check_{{$question_id}}">');

                //other column modifications comes here

            return $datatable->make(true);
        }
```

First when my table had A few rows all things worked fine but when I added a large number of new records, `questionsDatatable` return empty value and cause datatables return an alert error.

what is problem ? and is there any parameter that can use to solve this problem?

**Update :**

I changed `questionsDatatable` method to below and used simple query builders but it cannot return all records and return empty set :

```
public function questionsDatatable (Request $request)
{

            $questions = DB::table('questions')->select(['question_id'])->get();

            return $questions->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query return proper result, this dataTable should work properly. So first you need to check that you code line:

`$questions = DB::table('questions')->select(['question_id'])->get();`

Once this line return correct result, go through the [dataTable example](https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side).

Hope this information will help you.